# Display all files in MAMP PRO htdocs through the browser

Tags: osx-mavericks, mamp, mamp-pro

I recently acquired MAMP PRO for my mac so that I could host WordPress sites that I am developing locally. My other local server solution called Desktop Server allows me to view a list of websites that I am developing when I visit localhost in the web browser.

However I have searched Google for an answer to this and would ideally like to have a similar setup with MAMP ie when I visit localhost:8888 I would like to see all the links to sites that I am developing and be able to click on them to access them.

At the moment my development sites are running in the sites folder in MAC OSX Mavericks. When I visit localhost:8888 I get the mac's personal web sharing page running which may be because the native apache server is running.

If you have any thoughts on this please let me know?

Comment: More info here: http://serverfault.com/questions/275925/disabling-apache-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late with my answer but have to turn off apache first running this

sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

you have to remove index.php or any other index.html etc from your htdocs in Mamp

To allow a web server to produce a directory listing, whenever you point a directory without index file. Add following line in your .htaccess file of your local server

Options +Indexes